# Swing - Can Enter be used for focus traversal and action performed?

Tags: java, swing, focus, joptionpane

I understand that this is a ridiculous (and somewhat embarrassing) scenario and one which I am beginning to believe is not actually possible to overcome...

I have developed a basic swing application for my client which consists of a frame containing text fields and combo boxes which validates / processes the data captured when they lose focus - standard issue stuff.

My client is hell-bent on living in the "DOS days" by being able to traverse from field to field using the `ENTER` key instead of the default `TAB` key.

I achieved this simply and neatly by implementing `KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(...)`. (See below for full code)

At certain points during data being captured I need to show an error or warning message and I achieve this by the obvious `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentComponent, message, "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE)` routine.

**The problem** - when faced with the dialog message box, my client expects that he can then press `ENTER` to close it which no longer works because I have obviously overridden the `actionPerformed` event of `ENTER` and instead have assigned it as a focus traversal key.

I am aware that `SPACE` works perfectly instead to fire off the `actionPerformed` event on the Ok button which in turn merrily closes the dialog box. The issue is my client wants to be able to press `ENTER`...

I am trying to avoid creating a custom dialog message box but even if I attempted this I don't think I will be able to achieve the result I want because of my next point...

I have tried using `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parentComponent, message, "Error", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null, buttons, null)` instead where `buttons` is an array of pre-created buttons that I can add action / key / focus listeners onto to try re-create the default behaviour of the `ENTER` key. The problem is that `ENTER` no longer registers at all in any of these event listeners as long as I am assigning it as a focus traversal key.

This is how I am setting `ENTER` (and `ESC`, `TAB` and `SHIFT+TAB`) as focus traversal keys:

```
// Enable Enter & Tab as forward traversal keys and Esc & Shift-Tab as backward traversal keys
KeyStroke esc = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
KeyStroke shiftTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
Set<KeyStroke> forwardKeys = new HashSet<KeyStroke>();
forwardKeys.add(enter);
forwardKeys.add(tab);
Set<KeyStroke> backwardKeys = new HashSet<KeyStroke>();
backwardKeys.add(esc);
backwardKeys.add(shiftTab);
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, forwardKeys);
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, backwardKeys);
```

Any idea if this is possible or should I just tell my client to deal with it and get used to pressing `SPACE`?

Thanks in advance,

Xandel

Answer (score 0):

try this on the okButton and enter will start working but after this tab shift+tab also won't work on button.

```
    okButton.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
```